# pattern for interconnected algorithms

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose I am creating a payroll system. The amount of pay depends on many things. Here are some families of classes that have an effect on the computation:

**Employee Type:** Regular, Contractual, etc.

**Time Record Type:** Normal, Overtime, etc.

**Location:** DeliverySite, ClientSite, etc.

I imagine that those three families would each represent an inheritance hierarchy. However, each family type would have an effect on the payroll computation.

For example, the payment of a Regular employee with Normal time records at the DeliverySite would be different than the payment of a Regular employee with Normal time records at the ClientSite. At the same time, the payment of a Regular employee with Overtime time records at a DeliverySite would be different from the payment of a Regular employee at a Client site. And so on.

How can I model this? I was thinking of some combination of Strategy / Chain of Responsibility but I can't quite figure out how the implementation would look like.

Comment: What will happen with the calculation algorithm, when you add new employee type, or record type or location type? Or when you add new "family"?

Comment: Ideally there should only be minimal changes when a new implementation (subclass) of an existing family is added. The hard part is when a new family altogether is added - if the families reference each other (best solution I can think of so far), then adding a new family might introduce many difficult changes. In any case, either of those two scenarios would affect the algorithm.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked what kind of business rules will change when new subclass is added. Of course the design should minimize changes. But we can't suggest you anything if we don't know details about the whole calculation process.

Comment: The computation of the pay would be affected if either a new subclass is added or if a new family appears. Perhaps some multiplier would be applied, or the rates would be sourced from a different table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Decorator pattern is able to add new functionality/calculations with each layer you add to your object. You can dynamically add these afterwards without the need to refactor your current code.

You start out with a basic class and you'll add new "layers" (decorating) this object.

A good example of the use of the Decorator pattern can be found here : http://ima.udg.edu/~sellares/EINF-ES1/DecoratorToni.pdf